# How to make sure Macro workbook don't close while closing other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Scenario**

I have a userform whereby excel workbook will be hidden while opening using the following method of `Application.Visible = False`. These are the codes

**My userform**

[image]

`show excel` button is `Commandbutton1`
`hide excel` button is `Commandbutton2`

**This workbook**

[image]

**Codes**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call hideExcel
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

**Userform1**

[image]

**Codes**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Else
        Application.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call hideExcel
End Sub
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call hideExcel
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Else
        Application.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
Sub userform_click()
    Call hideExcel
End Sub
```

**Module**

[image]

**Codes**

```
Sub hideExcel()
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
    Else
        Application.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Problem**

The problem I am facing is

1. Open my macro and userform activated. Lets call this file `A`
2. Then open another workbook. Lets call this file `B`
3. Tried to close file `B` while workbook `A` is hidden. But there is a prompt to close file `A` also and eventually all excel will be closing including my macro file which is `A`.

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where the problem is? If you are closing last visible (not hidden) workbook, Excel also tries to close all other open workbooks (even if they're hidden). And I think it's normal Excel behavior. You can only avoid to see a prompt, e.g. by setting up `Workbook.Saved` property to `True` or by setting up `Application.DisplayAlerts` property to `False` or just by saving workbook before closing.

If you don't want to close hidden workbook you just have to make it visible before closing the second workbook.

Comment: My question is not about application display alerts. Like i mentioned in my question, scenario is; `userform` is active and `ThisWorkbook` is hidden. But meanwhile when try to close another workbook which is not hidden, whole excel will be closing including `userform` and `ThisWorkbook` for that userform.